# Date picker datetime-local Input type

Tags: html, jsp

Am having a jsp page
Am using a html control for date  using  input type="datetime-local".
Now i have to set  a value from database for this when this page is displayed after a save operation. few other  columns are getting pre populated with value. but the date column doesnt work as needed.

checked by changing the control to text  type and value was getting displayed  .

value coming to the variable is  like  Eg :**20-12-2022 17:23:01**
tried to  replace space and converted to  this format and daiplayed as well and not working

**20-12-2022T17:23:01**

```
<input 
type="datetime-local" 
id="dtid" 
name="frmDt" 
value="<%=myDataList.get(3).toString()%>"   />
```

Comment: You should format from dd-mm-yyyy... to yyyy-mm-dd format, so instead of "20-12-2022 17:23:01" use "2022-12-20 17:23:01". This works for me: `<input type="datetime-local" value="2022-12-20 17:23:01">`

Comment: The value coming fromdb was formatted as suggested above. i dont see any change. value is not hardcoded.But taken from an array list

Comment: you suggested you receive this format from the db: "20-12-2022 17:23:01". Please be more specific.

Comment: If you mean the format you receive from db is something like "2022-09-01T10:55:41.000Z" then you should google "convert postgresql db format". You didn't even specify which db you use.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in esponse  .Am using Mysql . The value  coming from db is    in format   eg :    30-12-2022 18:04:00 .   I can display the  value in  a text box.  But value i want to be preloaded in a control  <input type="datetime-local"    >. Its a JSP  form. i tried to format the string  using .replaceAll("\\s","T")  function aswell but not working.

Comment: OK, then format date from 30-12-2022 to 2022-12-31 and send that value to the input control. (see my first answer)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the datetime-local input type in my ReactJS application, but I was having trouble getting the date in the format that I wanted. The default format returned `2023-02-26T11:46` by the input type was not suitable for my needs and I want `09/19/18 13:55:26` this format.

After some research and experimentation, I was able to modify the code to get the desired date format. Here's what worked for me:

```
<input
    type='datetime-local'
    name='stating-time'
    value={endDT}
    onChange={e => {
        const date = new Date(e.target.value);
        const formattedDate = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'});
        setEndDT(formattedDate);
    }}
/>
```

In the above code, I first create a new Date object from the input value, then format the date using the toLocaleString() method with the desired options to produce the desired date format. I then replace the space character with the "T" character to convert the date string to the required format.